# RxJS 5.5.0-beta : mergeMap behavior differing from map + mergeAll

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I am having trouble creating a reproducible example so bear with me.

I have a library I created that wraps async API responses in an Observable. Simplifying greatly, the library has functions like `lib.ask("end-point")` that return an Observable with the response of the API call to that end point.

I want to run that API call every time another event happens. I'm attempting to model that with some version of mergeMap/switchMap/concatMap, depending on the situation. Let's use mergeMap as an example.

If I use map + mergeAll, it works just fine. I am writing it like so:

```
var responses$ = event$.pipe(
    map(()=>lib.ask("end-point")),
    mergeAll()
);
```

When I subscribe to responses$, I get my response!

However, if I rewrite the same chain with mergeMap instead, it does not work:

```
var responses$ = event$.pipe(
    mergeMap(()=>lib.ask("end-point"))
);
```

In this case, when I subscribe I do not get any results. It almost appears as if the inner subscription never gets made.

Like I said, I am struggling to create a reproducible example. I have attempted to debug what RxJS does to try to find where this thing is failing, but have not been able to figure it out. If anyone can think of why or in what situations mergeMap would behave differently than map + mergeAll, that might help me figure out where my problem is.

Comment: This could be just my ignorance, but what is `pipe`? Is it just for chaining operators?

Comment: Without a repro, I don't think there's much that can be said. The introduction of `pipe` was more of a re-arrangement than anything else, so if a bug was introduced in re-arranging the RxJS codebase, it ought to be of the type that's easy to reproduce. I think this question needs either the actual code that fails or a repro. And as soon as you have a repro, create an RxJS GitHub issue.